# save model values on edit page using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have the following `linq` query:

```
for (int i = 0; i < product.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
{
    listInsertproductvalue.Add(new AB_Product_vs_Field
    {
        Product_ID = product.Product_ID,
        Field_ID = FieldID,
        Field_Value_EN = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN,
        Field_Value_AR = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_AR,

    }); 
};
db.Entry(listInsertproductvalue).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

once I'm going to save model values to the database table I'm getting the following error:

> The entity type List`1 is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

These are the models:

```
public class ProductEdit
{
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }        
    public string Field_ID { get; set; }
    ...

    public IList<AB_Product_vs_Field> ListProductFields { get; set; }
    ...
}

public partial class AB_Product_vs_Field
{
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }
    public string Field_ID { get; set; }
    public string Field_Value_EN { get; set; }
    public string Field_Value_AR { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: `listInsertproductvalue` is a collection of `AB_Product_vs_Field` items. Best guess is you want to save each `AB_Product_vs_Field` in the collection?

Comment: I want to save `[0]` th value only

Comment: Then `db.Entry(listInsertproductvalue.First()).State = ....` although its unclear why you have a collection. Why not just create a single `AB_Product_vs_Field` object based on the first item in the `ListProductFields` collection and save it?

Comment: In fact you seem to be creating a duplicate collection from the first (`ListProductFields`) one. It could be just `db.Entry(ListProductFields[0]).State = ....`. Not really sure what your tyrig to do here.

Comment: What does this question have to do with LINQ. That's not a LINQ query; it's a for loop.